# popup window resource like spotify share window

Tags: php, jquery, popup, spotify

I'm looking for creating a tiny popup window on a mouse click that is similar to the spotify window that contains the link and share icons. Modal windows and alert windows are in the center of the page and not what I am looking for. What I want is a small window that opens right next to the link they click on.

Any resources on the internet? I have no issues paying for resources.

I'd like it to be driven by `jQuery` if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to create this menu (that I can think of) is having the menu element inline but hidden. Then using jQuery's [`onclick`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), have the element revealed. A combination of `relative` and `absolute` positioning is used to make the menu appear to the bottom right of the menu button ([this article](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) is a great resource for explaining this trick). I've modeled the demo below from the Spotify desktop UI using these principles.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/MdT8S/4/)

Comment: Perfect! I need to think about a few more things before I approve the answer but this is precisely what I need at the moment. Thanks.